# socket.io common server and client code

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build an app with node.js, socket.io and express.

I have a public directory which contains all the client code and that is sent to client via express

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I have some server code that resides in the root directory. I want to now add some classes which will be common to both server and client side code ( I will create objects in both the places) Where do I put these common modules and what is the best way of using them. I did not find anything related to this on their side and there isn't much documentation around it.

Comment: You would put them somewhere under `public`.

Comment: there has to be module.export for server, where as client does not need that and throws an error

Comment: @sublime indeed. what the error says exactly? (imho: the problem is that you cannot call `export` on `undefined` -- a remedy would be to just create `module={export:undefined}` in window scope)

Comment: @sublime You will need to package your modules differently then.  Consider using Require.js or similar to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to share js code between client and server, although it feels a bit *clumsy*.

First of all, node makes use of modules, so to overcome it we have to create an *artificial* variable on the `global scope` or generate some `ReferenceErrors`.

Second of all, shared-classes have to leave on the `global scope`, as well (of course to minimize the risk we can put them in a single `namespace`).

Do not know what is your particular context, but I think that in the long run it may be somehow difficult to keep those worlds (client-side and server-side) together, anyway.

Btw. in case you would decide for the shared version, you can create a new folder `shared` and then just call in server code:

```
 app.use("/shared", express.static(__dirname + "/shared"));
```

to statically service its content.